# A user's bio has a curse word in it

Tags: support, flags, profile-page

A person has a curse word in their "about me" area. Should I flag one of their posts, because I don't see and don't know how to flag a user without flagging on a post, and I don't see a flag button to flag the user on their bio or their page. I know swearing is not allowed on Stack Overflow, and if there is swearing you should flag it, but I can't flag the user page.

I have read about swearing. I don't see anything written about flagging and swearing on the about me or on the users' page. I only see *Flagging a question or answer*, *Flagging a comment* and that is it.

Should I flag one of the user's posts because of this swearing?

Here is the swearing:

> the python ***Bad word here (Something like dumb@)***

Also, I think there should be a flag button on a user's page or bio.
[image: Screenshot of user page]

Comment: Is it just a curse word or does it cross breaching [the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: Isn't a curse word breaching the CoC? Im sure bad words breach the CoC.

Comment: @AunZaidi not on its own. Only when it's directly offending someone or a group of people on purpose.

Comment: Also, I can't see anything wrong, even not tiny, in "the python d)mba_$" looks like some code, no curse, not offensive. No green what how you see this is "curse".

Comment: I he wrote something a bit more worse I just changed it so it does not look bad also cause I don't want to get banned

Comment: So don't include it. If you want you can put the full "curse" after `!>` markup this will mark it as "spoiler" and hide it by default.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I am very sure putting it as a spoiler will get you a warn or ban

Comment: I'm even more sure it won't.

Comment: LOL. That's not even the About Me section. That's SO only field used to describe the user's job title. The user is offending themselves, if anything. haha. (I'm laughing because it went to even more minor thing than I thought, having "python is dumbass" in actual About Me *might*, in very very slim chance, be offending to someone. But like this? Not a chance.)

Comment: For a moment I thought Tarte was the bad word, and I always thought it was a baked good.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah this word might make people hungry, they eat, and get mad for eating. So this word is really bad and must not be ever used!

Comment: 'PHP' ?  .......

Comment: "dumbass" isn't swearing, unless you think "stupid donkey" is swearing.

Comment: @khelwood dumbass no, but "stupid donkey"... Gordon Ramsey has really cemented that pair of words to mean the utter annihilation of a person :) But in this case it is in reference to oneself... what are we even talking about. I mean its certainly unprofessional to put such things on Stack Overflow, but conducting yourself in a professional manner remains a personal choice.

Answer (score -19):

You should flag one of their posts, or if they have none, one of yours with a custom flag. Be *very* clear what the issue is.

Comment: Umm.... no? Any sensible mod should decline such flag on spot, same as flag for user having "Hello! I'm Kevin" and someone flags "I'm offended by the name Kevin". It's their right to flag, sure, but it's bad advice as it will (or SHOULD) lead to flag being declined.